# How To Find Location By IP Address without using APIs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is there a way in either JavaScript or C# to find a user's location by their IP address without querying a third party's API?

Comment: why you have restricted? without using any API.

Comment: There is no easy and free at the same time method. By all means you will need some database to look up (GeoIP http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing, for example). Then, if you don't want to use any API, you should set up your own database and import GeoIP data in it.

Comment: I don't understand what was a thought behind not to use API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way in javascript or C# class to do this plz

No, there isn't. That's the reason why people have built entire databases with IP addresses and provided APIs for it.

Answer (score 3):

How do you think it will work, how can you resolve the location? Do you have a database with all the information? No, right. We have to use some service on the  web and get the location. There are a lot of simple API's offering those services.

Try this, I use this mostly and the result can be a JSON or XML or CSV

**freegeoip.net**

```
http://freegeoip.net/{format}/{ip}
http://freegeoip.net/json/216.239.51.99
```

So, for this you will get a result like

```
{
    "ip": "216.239.51.99",
    "country_code": "US",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "region_code": "CA",
    "region_name": "California",
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "zipcode": "94043",
    "latitude": 37.4192,
    "longitude": -122.0574,
    "metro_code": "807",
    "areacode": "650"
}
```

You can parse this very easily. Let me know if you have any other questions about that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that I am aware of.

To understand why you need to look at how IP Geolocation works: IP addresses don't necessarily come with the location information attached to them. To find out which country an IP address belongs to you have to do a lookup in a huge database of IP addresses and their locations.

IP Geolocation providers assemble these databases from a variety of sources. The [Geolocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) entry on Wikipedia gives a more detailed explanation where the information actually comes from. These providers collect information from many sources, match the information and create a database from it. This is a somewhat complicated process which is why you are usually charged to access these databases.

In theory you could create or download your own database and then query that. However, this is not really feasible. You would have to spent a lot of resources to create your own database. Downloading will not be easy as the Geolocation providers will not want to give their databases away with charging for access being their business model. Also remember that you will need to maintain your database as IP addresses are reallocated frequently.